# Converting PHP 5.6 code to 5.4 - unexpected '.'

Tags: php

i have prestashop module that is compatible only with PHP 5.6+, but my site is running PHP 5.4, so i am converting the code to PHP 5.4

I have this problem i cant figure out. Its: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ')'

```
public static $files = array (
    '15527491986d870fa01b8ac01c3aae85' => __DIR__ . '/../..' . '/src/GdprCustomScript.php',
);
```

I suppose the problem is the dot after **DIR**, should i change the dot for comma?

Comment: Try removing the comma at the end and see if it works. Because there is only one item in that array.

Comment: Nope, not working

Comment: How about this? `public static $files = array ('15527491986d870fa01b8ac01c3aae85' => __DIR__ . '/../../src/GdprCustomScript.php');`

Comment: What's the purpose of this dot `' . '`

Comment: Prior to 5.6 you cannot do anything more complicated than assignment in the parameter declarations. Move that to the constructor. But sweet fancy baby jesus on a bike upgrade your PHP. Everything below 7.1 is [End-of-Life](https://secure.php.net/eol.php).

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix String concatenation.

Comment: @duskwuff, what he meant was, on either side of that dot, its strings! So why concatenating two strings where you can write it as single string itself.

Comment: @duskwuff - what they said ^

Answer (score 2):

[PHP 5.4 and 5.6 have both reached end-of-life.](http://php.net/eol.php) You should be migrating your code to PHP 7.1 or later, not to an older version.

Regardless -- [constant expressions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php) were a new feature in PHP 5.6. There is no way to declare a static class variable using an expression in PHP 5.4.

In theory, you could initialize the variable in code following the class, e.g.

```
class Whatever {
    …
    public static $files;
    …
}

Whatever::$files = array( … );
```

However, I'll reiterate that **you need to migrate to a supported version of PHP**. PHP 5.4 has been end-of-life since September 2015. If your web host does not support any newer versions, you need to find a better web host.

Answer (score -1):

try old method :

```
public static $files = array (
'15527491986d870fa01b8ac01c3aae85' => dirname(__FILE__) . '/../..'       . '/src/GdprCustomScript.php',
  );
```

just

```
__DIR__ -> dirname( __FILE__ )
```

Comment: `__DIR__` ist since PHP 5.3 available

Comment: That doesn't work in *any* version of PHP, even modern ones -- ["Fatal error: Constant expression contains invalid operations"](https://3v4l.org/8KWF4)